# How to merge two different queries

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have these two tables in PostgreSQL.

```
TABLE "Likes" (
    id,
    post-id (foreign key pointing to "Post" table)
)

TABLE "Post" (
    id,
    body,
    date
)
```

What I want to do is fetch all posts and the number of likes each one has.

I've written this query:

```
SELECT "post-id", COUNT(*) AS "likes" FROM "Likes"
GROUP BY "post-id";
```

Which will return something like this:

```
-------------------
| post-id | likes |
-------------------
| 1       | 9     |
-------------------
| 4       | 2     |
-------------------
```

But I still need to merge this query with the one that fetches all information about posts... So in the end, I want something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| id | likes | body                  | date       |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 9     | This is a post!       | 2017-05-03 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 2  |       | Tasdasdas!            | 2017-05-03 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 4  | 2     | This is another post! | 2017-05-04 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 5  |       | ssdasdasdadadass      | 2017-05-04 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

My problem is that I don't know how to add the "likes" column to the query that fetch all posts, since only **some** posts have likes.

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is typical case for `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT    post.*, COUNT(likes.id) likes
FROM      post
LEFT JOIN likes ON post.id = likes.post_id
GROUP BY  post.id
```

This way, you can `SELECT post.*` because `GROUP BY post.id` implies a [functional dependency](https://www.depesz.com/2010/08/08/waiting-for-9-1-recognize-functional-dependency-on-primary-keys/).

*Sidenote*: your identifiers are named really oddly. You should try to avoid the need for quoting identifiers, it will just make your queries harder to read.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! :D Also, I don't usually use the quotes, but for some reason I'm forced to, otherwise it won't work. I'm using phpPgAdmin to manage the database and test the queries, and it gives errors if the identifiers aren't all inside quotation marks.

Comment: @Tirafesi I'm not saying that you just don't need quotation. You really need it, when you have identifiers like that. I'm saying that you should not use identifiers like that in the first place. Or, at least, your work would be simpler without them. But if you can live with it, use them.

Comment: I don't get what you mean... Could you show me an example of what a correct identifier would be?

Comment: @Tirafesi like the ones in the answer. I.e. all lower-case, starting with a letter (not a number) & uses underscore to separate words (if you need a separator at all). -- Upper-case letters, and `-` cause you to use quotation.

Comment: Aah. So what's wrong is the actual table names? Instead of creating a table named Post, it should have been named post?

Comment: @Tirafesi technically, `"Post"` is not wrong either. But then, you'll **need** to use `"Post"` everywhere. But if you write `post`, you can use `Post`, `POST` (or every case-combination). If you use quotation nowhere, your identifiers will be in a [case-insensitive "mode"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know that :D I learned databases using SQLite, and it didn't have this problem there, and in classes we'd always name tables with Uppercase

Answer (score 1):

```
Select p.id, c."likes", p.body, p.date
from Posts p
left join
(
SELECT "post-id", COUNT(*) AS "likes" FROM "Likes"
GROUP BY "post-id"
) c on p.id = c."post-id";
```